# No parameters passed when ModelState is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having difficulties to understand what happens when ModelState is not valid (EF4.1, database first).

The following code shows creating a task for a project.

Whenever the model is valid, everything is OK, but when model is not valid, I got an exception that no parameter has been passed to model (however the route is correct and everything should be ok).
What am I doing wrong?

```
 //
    // POST: /Task/Create
    [Authorize()]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(int projectId, CPIO_Tasks task)
    {
        ViewBag.projId = projectId;

        try
        {            
            task.t_p_id = projectId;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.CPIO_Tasks.AddObject(task);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Projects", new { id = task.t_p_id });
            }

        }
        catch (DataException ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Nieudane dodanie:", ex.ToString());
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Task", new {id = projectId});
    }
```

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'projectId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(Int32)' in 'CPIO_WebUI.Controllers.TaskController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

The path with redirect id correct: localhost:11314/Task/Create/2.

Thanks in advance for any help

Anna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, for you to not pass a `projectId` to your method, you'd need to make your method look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? projectId, CPIO_Tasks task)
{
    // .....
}
```

What this does is use a `Nullable<int>` for the parameter taking the value type (which doesn't allow `null`) and making it a reference type to allow `null`.  That way you can pass a `null` value without running into this exception.

Comment: Thank you!!! I didn't think it was so simple. Now I have to read the books' section of routing once again! :)

Comment: @LadyRoot this may remove your exception, but I think it's highly unlikely that it's the right code.  From a POST action with an invalid model the *right* thing to do is almost always to simply render the view with the invalid model to allow the user to correct their errors. This might mean repopulating parts of the original model (which you're doing via the ViewBag), but you almost certainly don't want to redirect because you'll lose the error information. Renaming the parameter to `id` and leaving it non-nullable is also more likely correct because it's (probably) required in all cases.

Comment: Good point, just changed the hast `return RedirectToAction("Create", "Task", new {id = projectId});` to `return View(task)`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the model error is actually coming from your GET action, not your POST action.  Typically you wouldn't redirect when you have a model error, you'd simply return the same view with the model errors intact, regenerating the model as needed.  Without seeing your GET action, it's hard to say but try replacing the redirect at the end with a view result with a proper model and see if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: My Get action is as follows:`        // GET: /Task/Create
        [Authorize()]
        public ActionResult Create(int projectId)
        {
            ViewBag.projId = projectId;
            return View();
        } `

Comment: @LadyRoot - as shark says, your parameter needs to be named "id".  Still you don't want to be redirecting here.  You just want to return the view with the invalid model (to retain the model errors).